# Getting an error in docusign api explorer

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to populate the `textTabs` in one of the documents so that it has information prefilled into it using the call for `EnvelopeTabs: update`, however it keeps throwing me an error that it cannot find the tab that I am trying to test in the explorer. I have used the `list` call in the EnvelopeTabs to make sure that the information that I'm providing matches what is in the envelope and it is, here's an example of what I was seeing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ERw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Wrq.png)

When I make the call to `update` the tab in `textTabs`, I am doing it with the `documentId`, `pageNumber`, and `tabLabel` provided above and with the `value` set to what I want to be prefilled, however I keep getting an error that it cannot find the specified tab.

I have even tried filling it in with just the `tabId` and am still getting the same error.

In an effort to see if I was missing something, I also tried checking the linked reference documentation on the `EnvelopeTabs: update` page but it is 404ing (as were one or two other end points in the api explorer).

Any help would be appreciated as it seems like there is a piece of information that I'm missing to prefill tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the envelope via the API? If so, then the easy way to set a tab's value is to set the `value` parameter.

If you want to set a tab's value after the envelope is created, use the [EnvelopeRecipientTabs: update](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/update/) method. (Note the resource name in your question was incorrect.)

When using this method, or any other DocuSign `update` method, remember that it is not a `patch` method: You must supply *all* of the parameters for the Envelope Recipient Tab that you're updating. If you don't already have all of the settings, then first do a get on the object, then update it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using below JSON call to update the Recipient tab and its updating the tab value:

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

{
      "textTabs": [
                    {
                        "value":"newVal",
                        "tabId": "cef562dd-e098-4dcd-935d-34ff8f5b5211"
                    }
                ]
}
```